# Error connecting Hortonworks Hive ODBC in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, hadoop, hive, odbc, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to query Hortonworks Hive via ODBC Driver in Excel 2013.

I downloaded the driver here (32-bit):

http://hortonworks.com/downloads/

Hortonworks 2.5
Hive 2.5.0.0-1245

Then I add the config in ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit)

[image]

[image]

Everything seems fine.

Then when I go into Excel 2013 to build the query:

[image]

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

Anyone knows why?

Comment: [This](https://www.dynamics-pros.com/support/kb/kb102039) might help.  Namely, *"This error is related to the fact that you have 32-bit ODBC drivers which are not compatible with 64-bit Import Tool."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the Hive driver from Hortonworks. For some reason, it's not compatible with Excel or Power BI.

I downloaded Microsoft Hive ODBC from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40886 and everything works perfectly. Make sure to choose `SASL` and not `HTTP` when creating User DSN.