# Hive Query result to XL

Tags: excel, csv, hive, hiveql, export-to-csv

I am newbie to Hadoop and Hive. My current requirement is to collect the stats of number of records loaded in 15 tables on each run day. Instead of executing each `select Count(*)` query and copy output manually to XL. Could anyone suggest what is the best method to automate this task please?

Note: we are not having any GUI to run Hive Queries, submitting Hive queries in normal Unix terminal.

Comment: Small correction it is Select Count(*) not select * ..

Answer (score 3):

Export to the CSV or TSV file, then open file in Excel. Normally it generates TSV file (tab-separated). This is how to transform it to comma-separated if you prefer CSV;

```
hive -e "SELECT 'table1' as source,  count(*) cnt FROM db.table1
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'table2' as source,  count(*) cnt FROM db.table2" | tr "\t" "," > mydata.csv
```

Add more tables to the query.
You can mount directory in which you are writing output file in Windows using SAMBA/NFS. Schedule the command using crontab and voila, every day you have updated file.

Also you can connect directly using ODBC drivers:

https://mapr.com/blog/connecting-apache-hive-to-odbc/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver

[Error connecting Hortonworks Hive ODBC in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077130/error-connecting-hortonworks-hive-odbc-in-excel-2013)